# How to export a whole Eclipse project includes jars in Maven local repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, export, maven-repository

### Background

- I have an Eclipse project that uses Maven to manage the libraries (jars). All the jars used in that project are stored in the Maven repository.
- The development environment and the Maven repository is placed in the same *closed* network.
- There is another machine for the code static analysis (Parasoft Jtest). This server is placed in another network, so this machine can't access that Maven repository.
- The code static analysis product requires an Eclipse project without any build error for the analysis. You have to export a whole Eclipse project without build error and copy and import to Jtest.

### Problem

When you simply export an Eclipse project, it doesn't contain jars on the Maven repository. When you copy the exported project and copy it to Jtest, the Eclipse project can't be built because of missing jars.

### Question

Is there any way to export a whole Eclipse project including jars in Maven local repository and get an Eclipse project without build errors caused by mission jars?

Note 1: I want to keep the original Eclipse projects using the Maven repository to refer to the jars (doesn't contain jars in the Eclipse project itself). I want to add jars only for the exported Eclipse projects.

Note 2: You can get all jars required to run the application by exporting EARs. But I'd prefer not to do it because you have to pick up all jars included in EARs and add them to the exported Eclipse project manually.

Comment: The whole setup appears to be rather unfortunate. Wouldn't it be better to modernize the setup instead of trying to work around this peculiar restrictions?

Comment: What do those that set up this server suggest you do?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a folder containing all the jars resolved from the maven dependencies by doing an export from Eclipse as follows:

Export >> Java >> Runnable JAR File

Choose the option: `Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR`

Assuming you export to a jar at `/export_location/exported.jar` all the jars will be placed in `/export_location/exported_lib`

Eclipse can also create an ant script that you can reuse as part of a headless process to build this list.